# Facebook sharing using js

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

My objective is to post a user profile to Facebook and i am not able to post a dynamic data instead it is just showing website url.

i have created app id on facebook developer account, added my domain in it. included js in index file and onclick function i am calling  FB.init() and FB.ui() functions.

included js in main page

my onclick method

```
 function fshare(image,name){



  FB.init({appId: "myAppId", status: true, cookie: true});
   var share = {
      method: 'feed',
      picture: 'mydomain.com/images/competitors/' + image +'',
  name: name,
      link: 'mydomain.com',
      caption: 'Vote Now',
      description: 'Visit the profile and place vote',
   };

    FB.ui(share, function(response){
       if (typeof response == "undefined") {
    console.log("not shared");
       } else {

          console.log("shared");
        }
    });
  }
```

i want these profile image, link, caption and description to appear in share post but i am getting only link of the website.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Feed Dialog is not listed anymore: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/javascript/reference/FB.ui

All those parameters are deprecated anyway, you have to add them as Open Graph Tags in the source of the shared URL and Facebook will pick them up automatically. Just use the Share Dialog: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/share-dialog

Dynamic tags are not possible anymore, you have to use a different permanent URL if you want to show different tags.

Comment: so i have to design a different dynamic page for each person and use that url in share dialog

Comment: (The docs for FB.ui might not list the Feed dialog any more, but it still has its own page in the sharing section, https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/feed-dialog)

Comment: yes, you have to use a specific url for each set of og tags.